# How to put hint message/placeholder in Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I've written java script to use as Bookmarklet. Below is the code

```
javascript:(function(){
  var e=document.getElementById('text');
  if(e){e.value%20+='Input your Query';}
  document.getElementById(Email-textarea');
  if(f)  {f.value%20+=%20'@gmail.com';}
 })();
```

In the above code, after the text 'Input your Query', i want to put the Hint message(placeholder) to the users.How to achieve this.

Comment: What are you calling a "hint" ?

Comment: grayed out text(placeholder)

Comment: In that case I suggest setting the placeholder attribute...

Comment: I have set the placeholder attribute, but it is not working.

Comment: I have set the placeholder attribute, but it is not working(No placeholder text is getting displayed, instead it displays as normal text).